# CSS selector or XPath for elements without specific child

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath

Here is the example:

```
<ul>
    <li>list item one</li>
    <li>list item two
        <ol>
            <li test="video">Nested item one</li>
            <li test="audio">nested item two</li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
            <li test="video">Nested item three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>list item three</li>
</ul>
```

If I only want to select the elements of `<ol>` which does not have child `<li test="audio">`, what's the CSS selector or XPath please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//ol[not(li/@test="audio")]
```

will select all `ol` elements that do not have an `li` child with a `test` attribute value of `"audio"`.

---

<sub>*Update per OP follow-up comment adding the requirement that the `ol` element must also have a `li` child with a `test` attribute value of `"video"`...*</sub>

This XPath,

```
//ol[not(li/@test="audio") and li/@test="video"]
```

will select all `ol` elements that

- do *not* have an `li` child with a `test` attribute value of `"audio"`, and
- *do* have an `li` child with a `test` attribute value of `"video"`

Comment: Hi @kjhughes, thanks for your reply!! i forgot to mention in the question i want to select the element with child <li test="video">, but wihtout child <li test="audio">, is it possible? thanks in advance !!

Comment: @Judy: Answer updated to address your follow-up.